# TemplateInfo into Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

how can i get a form field id after submitting the form. im trying like this:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(logOnParts.Part.UserNameOrEmail)
```

but no work on controller side. i need to get "Part_UserNameOrEmail" something..

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(logOnParts.Part.UserNameOrEmail))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Part_UserNameOrEmail", "error");
    TempData["logon-focus-field"] = "Part_UserNameOrEmail";
}
```

so i will focus the field on view side like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TempData["logon-focus-field"]').focus();
});
```

Comment: Why? The controller shouldn't need that.

Comment: actualy im trying to do set focus the failed field when validating on controller side. so i need to get the field name is it? i need to post TempData["logon-focus-field"] = "logOn_Part_UserNameOrEmail" to view side after validating.

Comment: Are you using the built in validation? If so your field should be decorated with the `input-validation-error` css class. Use javascsript to set its focus.

Comment: no trying to do manually so doesnt work "$('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller should absolutely not need such information. The generated id is a view specific information. If you need this in a controller this simply means that you have some serious design problem with your application. Unfortunately as you haven't explained your scenario in the question it is difficult to help you solving this problem. So in your controller you could do this:

```
Expression<Func<MyViewModel, string>> expression = x => x.Part.UserNameOrEmail;
string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
string id = new TemplateInfo().GetFullHtmlFieldId(name);
```

Comment: well it works. im trying to set focus the field its failed when validating manually without ClientValidation or UnobtrusiveJavaScript.